# Do particle simulations in blender rebake the same if settings are not changed

Tags: particles, blend-files

I am getting ready to render a scene on a cloud computer that does not have opengl support  and so I have to render the scene using the command line. So I cannot use GUI to reload cache of particles. My question is if i just leave the settings unchanged in the particle system will the render be the same as if the baked data was reloaded in the GUI. Also perhaps there is a way to relink from command line only, anyone know how?

Comment: Baked data should be read correctly in background mode. What is happening in your case?

Comment: Leander what is background mode and how do i get it read if i change file directory name when i move to cloud computer?

Comment: Background mode is the non-gui mode which I assumed you where using on the computer which doesn't support open gl. Can you not use relative paths?